# WPF Popup not opening after first time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a popup window for selecting a color. The popup is supposed to open when I press down on the chooser button and close when a color is selected or the user clicks outside the area. This works the first time the popup opens. But after opening the first time the popup never opens again.

Chooser button class overview

```
public class RCTPaletteChooserButton : Button {

    public Popup popup { get { return GetTemplateChild("popup") as Popup; } }
    public RCTPaletteChooser chooser { get { return GetTemplateChild("chooser") as RCTPaletteChooser; } }

    static RCTPaletteChooserButton() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RCTPaletteChooserButton),
                   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RCTPaletteChooserButton)));

    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
        chooser.PaletteSelected += OnPaletteSelected;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    private void OnPaletteSelected(object sender, PaletteEventArgs e) {
        popup.IsOpen = false;
        RemapColor = e.RemapColor;
        RaiseEvent(new PaletteEventArgs(PaletteSelectedEvent, e.RemapColor));
    }

    // None of these 3 overrides work
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        RCTControls.PlayClick();
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
    protected override void OnLostMouseCapture(MouseEventArgs e) {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        base.OnLostMouseCapture(e);
    }
}
```

Content template of chooser button.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RCTPaletteChooserButton}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RCTPaletteChooserButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="image" Width="12" Height="12"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=image}"
                        Placement="Bottom" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False">
                        <local:RCTPaletteChooser x:Name="chooser" Focusable="False"/>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by modifying the following funcions in the chooser button class.

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    popup.StaysOpen = true;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e) {
    popup.StaysOpen = false;
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}
protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e) {
    popup.StaysOpen = false;
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}
protected override void OnLostMouseCapture(MouseEventArgs e) {
    // Function no longer needed
    base.OnLostMouseCapture(e);
}
```